# Can I use GT511C1 instead of GT511C3 finger-print scanner?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I've found 2 finger-print modules, **GT511C1** and **GT511C3**.

However most of the code examples and libraries have defined for using the name **'GT511c3'**. Can i use the same code examples and libraries for the **GT511c1**.

If there is an issue, what is the issue of using **GT511C1** instead if **GT511C3** module ?

Comment: This really belongs on the [Arduino SE](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the same code examples. The GT511C1 and GT511C3 are nearly identical. The GT511C3 can store 200 instead of 20 fingerprints and has an faster identification time (0.5s faster). The protocol/packet structure is the same.

Comment: thnk you very much.